# Summarise a data frame according a second data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have two different data frame, say df1 and df2 as follows:

```html
df1 <- read.table(text = " Class Head Group
A1 12 1
A2 11 2
A3 10 1
A4 9 2
A5 10 1
", header = TRUE)

df2 <- read.table(text = " Temp1 Temp2 Temp3 Temp4 Temp5
13 13 14 11 17
13 8 19 14 15
14 2 20 15 14
15 7 9 19 9
", header = TRUE)
```

I want to get frequencies in Temps given df1 for each class and Head. Temp1 corresponds to A1, Temp2 corresponds to A2 and so on. So, for example, 
if I see a value< 12 ( see Head for A1) in Temp1, I will count them. In Temp1 all values great than 12 in Head , so the No=0 for A1. For A2, you see 11 in df1, so I need 
to look at Temp2 and I see 3 values (8,2,7) are less than than 11, so No=3 for A2 and so on...

I want to get the following outcome:

```html
Class Head No
A1 12 0
A2 11 3
A3 10 1
A4 9 0
A5 19 1
```

I tried map2, but I was unsuccessful as tibble columns were not consistent lengths. So I wonder if we could do it in R

Comment: In your post,  the tags are `dplyr/tidyverse`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One `base R` solution could be:

```
df1$No <- colSums(sweep(df2, 2, FUN = "<", df1$Head))

  Class Head Group No
1    A1   12     1  0
2    A2   11     2  3
3    A3   10     1  1
4    A4    9     2  0
5    A5   10     1  1
```

Comment: Thanks, how I can remove  the Group column, tmfmnk

Comment: Here, you can use `df1[-3]` after the line in my post.

Comment: Thank you, I like your codes, simple but very professional

Answer (score 0):

We can convert the second dataset to 'long' format, do a `left_join` and get the count on a logical expression

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df2 %>%
    rename_all(~ as.character(df1$Class)) %>% 
    pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = 'Class') %>% 
    left_join(df1) %>%
    group_by(Class) %>% 
    summarise(Head = first(Head), No = sum(value < Head)) 
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#  Class  Head    No
#  <chr> <int> <int>
#1 A1       12     0
#2 A2       11     3
#3 A3       10     1
#4 A4        9     0
#5 A5       10     1
```

---

In `base R`, we can replicate the 'Head' column and use that to compare

```
df1$No <- colSums(df2 < df1$Head[col(df2)])
df1[-3]
#  Class Head No
#1    A1   12  0
#2    A2   11  3
#3    A3   10  1
#4    A4    9  0
#5    A5   10  1
```